# Same Colour for a legend in all charts

Tags: vba, excel, charts, pie-chart

```
Table 1 - E(40%),C(20%),D(20%),A(10%), B(10%),
Table 2 - D(60%),C(15%),A(15%),B(10%)
Table 3 -  F(40%),C(20%),A(10%),B(10%),D(10%),E(10%)
```

Suppose I take Table 3 as the base chart.How to keep same color for A,B,C,D,E in all charts arranged in descending order of % share (charts in different sheets)
[image: img]

Comment: Can you show some example of what you mean please?

Answer (score 0):

Another excellent case study why pie charts are not good data visualisation.

Excel assigns the pie wedge colors according to their order. The first wedge (starts at 12 o'clock) is blue, the second red, the third green, etc. according to the chosen color theme.

The size of the slice or its series name is totally irrelevant.

If you want to order the slices by size, then you will need to manually assign the same color to series A in all charts, or use a macro to do that.

Of course, it would be so much easier to use horizontal bar charts, with all bars the same color. Then the reader can focus on the data values without having to evaluate distracting colors and flicking back and forth between pie and legend to understand what they are seeing.

Just for kicks: a panel with three horizontal bar charts. Quickly tell me: What is the name of the second smallest item in Table 3? Can you see how much easier that is to see in the bar charts than in the pies? No colors, no legends.

[image]

Comment: please share the macro

Comment: Excuse me? It looks like you are confusing this site with a free coding service. Please read the FAQ and take the [Tour]

Answer (score -1):

## Macro to keep same color.

First fill cells with same color corresponding to A,B,C...F in all sheets. Then create all three pie charts and run macro

```
Sub ColorPies()
Dim cht As ChartObject
Dim i As Integer
Dim vntValues As Variant
Dim s As String
Dim myseries As Series

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each sh In Worksheets
    sh.Activate
     For Each cht In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
        For Each myseries In cht.Chart.SeriesCollection

            If myseries.ChartType <> xlPie Then GoTo SkipNotPie
            s = Split(myseries.Formula, ",")(2)
            vntValues = myseries.Values

            For i = 1 To UBound(vntValues)
                myseries.Points(i).Interior.Color = Range(s).Cells(i).Interior.Color
            Next i
SkipNotPie:
        Next myseries
    Next cht
    Next sh
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```